# phpMyAdmin 4.5.4, Unexpected token error in REPLACE statement

Tags: replace, phpmyadmin, token

Below query is running successful in phpMyAdmin 3.5.3 version.

```
SELECT  *
FROM mytable
WHERE REPLACE (Col, 'a', '')  = 'bbb'
```

But after I upgraded `phpMyAdmin` to `version 4.5.4.1`, it got below errors at `WHERE` clause near `REPLACE`. 
This error can reproduce any database with any table. 
[image]

If I change the query to below, it is working.

```
SELECT  *
FROM mytable
WHERE (REPLACE (Col, 'a', ''))  = 'bbb'
```

Is it the bug of phpMyAdmin?  OR MySQL plan to change its  syntax not to support without parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug with the parser library used by phpMyAdmin. I've opened a bug report at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/43 but it seems to have been already fixed; for instance I'm not able to reproduce it inversion 4.5.5.1. I suggest you upgrade your phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

try this, means your 2nd options

```
SELECT  *
FROM mytable
WHERE (REPLACE (Col, 'a', ''))  = 'bbb'
```

and its also working(in 4.4.6) without round brackets,

**Edited**

but I just tested in **4.5** & **4.6**, seems **round brackets** are must, as per new standards

Comment: Is it new standard of phpMyAdmin or MySQL ?

Comment: well as per my knowledge, its new standard by phpMyadmin, I just upgraded to `phpMyadmin 4.6 alpha` and having old mysql (5.5 v, didnt upgraded this), so its not working without round brackets. also if you type multiple queries without `;` it will also show you error, so its mean its by phpMyadmin new standards

Comment: What should be the reason of phpMyAdmin to change standard which not backward compatible?  I do not see any official announce or changelog in phpMyAdmin site.

Comment: Well, I am not aware of the reason, but what my understanding is, as we developer are very lazy to follow the standards, So, may be they thought to implement strict standards to increase efficiency. :-)